# First Character of a String

Tags: string, function

```js
function doWeirdStuff(number, string) {
   if ((number = 0 || string[0] == "o")) {
       console.log("Oooooops");
   }

doWeirdStuff(7, "Oello");
```

Here is the function and parameter. The question is if `string[0]=="H"` and string first number is also H, it logs "Oooops", but if `string[0]=="h"`, then it doesn't log "Oooops", and the opposite also happens the same.

Is it possible to make it so that there is no difference between capital and small letters?

I am changing the first letters and it doesn't produce the results I expect.

Comment: is this javascript?

Comment: force the input to upper case before comparing? `string = string.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Yes, it's Javascript.

Comment: Did you mean `if (number == 0 ...` instead of `if (number = 0 ...`?